# Linux screen cmd execute not working?

Tags: java, linux, gnu-screen

I am running this via java.

```
String cmd = "screen -dmS test -X eval \'stuff \"stop \\015\"\'";    

try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();  }
```

And it prints as

```
screen -dmS test -X eval 'stuff "stop\015"'
```

However in the screen i am trying to run it on, i see this:

```
-X: Missing ' quote.   AND     -X: Missing " quote.
```

[image]

Where is the quote missing? If i run that command through console it works fine.

Comment: Why are you using `+` when there are no variables in your string?

Comment: To escape the quotes, it prints exactly how i want it to, so im not sure why that would be a problem.

Comment: You use the following `String cmd = "screen -dmS test -X eval \'stuff \"stop \\015\"\'";`

Comment: That prints fine as well, but im still seeing -X: Missing " quote.

Comment: Which one is it claiming to be missing? In your question, you said ' but in your reply you said "

Comment: Do `System.out.println(cmd)` and copy the command then run it in the console.

Comment: Copying and pasting it after printing works fine. But running it through .exec(cmd) does not.

Comment: @JoelLord it actually flickers to " first, then it says '

Comment: Ive updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this once :-

```
String cmd[] = {"screen","-dmS","test","-X","eval", "'stuff","\"stop\\015\"'"};
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();  }
```

Comment: Still says missing quote.

Comment: All good, I think i will find another way of doing this without using screen.